# Guzzle Http error maximum execution time exceeded

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have an API route in Laravel that is responsible for exchanging auth code with the access token. However, when calling it, it seems to be getting the following.

> PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

This is my code which lives in routes/api.php

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as GuzzleRequest;

Route::post('/token', function (Request $request) {
    $client = new Client();
    $url = config('app.url') . '/oauth/token';
    $body = [
        'grant_type' => $request->input('grant_type'),
        'client_id' => $request->input('client_id'),
        'client_secret' => $request->input('client_secret'),
        'redirect_uri' =>  $request->input('redirect_uri'),
        'code' =>  $request->input('code'),
    ];
    $request = new GuzzleRequest('POST', $url, [], json_encode($body));
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
        // Handle the successful response
        $responseData = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        return response()->json($responseData);
        // Process the response data as needed
    })->otherwise(function ($exception) {
        // Handle the error
        // $exception->getMessage() contains the error message
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $exception->getMessage()
        ]);
    });

    $promise->wait();
});
```

Comment: Why don't you handle the request in synchronous mode ?

Comment: And, depending on the laravel version, why not use the `Http` facade?

Comment: Change in your php.ini max_execution_time = 120 to max_execution_time = 1200

Comment: @Wildfire i tried synchronous mode and it shows the same error

Comment: @desh it's php error. change the .ini